# Clicking a link to remote file and editing with local app

Tags: cgi, executable, local

I would like to be able to click a link which has the directory path to a remote server and be able to open a local application (namely notepad++) to edit the remote file.

I can map a drive to the remote server to allow the notepad++.exe to have a local path to look for when trying to run the application... I just need a way to get a link click to automatically open notepad++.exe with the remote file for editing.

Any ideas? I know I am vague quite a bit here but please ask for any clarifications or other dependencies you might think could work that I might add into the requirements of this question and I will be happy to respond.

Thanks for any help!

Cheers!

Comment: Is this a programming question?  Sure doesn't look like one...  where's the source code? ;-)

Comment: Yes this is a programming question how would you code this into a web page to allow for users to click a link to open a local application with a remote server path to a file to be edited it's a multi-faceted question with inclining of non-programming problems but programming still involved)...
I actually just found a solution about an hour ago. Basically needed to do a javascript call passing an ActiveX object with the files location on the remote server on click and then opening a shell via javascript passing the notepad++.exe path with the file path to the remote file to open.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a programming question how would you code this into a web page to allow for users to click a link to open a local application with a remote server path to a file to be edited it's a multi-faceted question with inclining of non-programming problems but programming still involved)... I actually just found a solution about an hour ago. Basically needed to do a javascript call passing an ActiveX object with the files location on the remote server on click and then opening a shell via javascript passing the notepad++.exe path with the file path to the remote file to open.